# SIGUSR1 Signal is not triggering

Tags: c, signals

I'm starting to learn signals and how to trigger them. I have this simple code that triggers a signal using SIGUSR1, but when I run the code, the only thing that gets printed is the "Starting..." line. Nothing else gets printed. Am I doing something wrong?

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void my_handler(int signum)
{
    printf("Hello\n");
    printf("%d\n", signum);
    if (signum == SIGUSR1) {
        printf("Receveid\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("Starting...\n");
    signal(SIGUSR1, my_handler);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you sending the signal?

Comment: Your program exits immediately, you'll never have time to send the signal.

Comment: **I have this simple code that triggers a signal using SIGUSR1** No you don't. You have code that registers a handler for the signal, you have nothing to trigger the signal.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm not understanding signals correctly then. If signal(SIGUSR1, my_handler) only registers it, then I'm not sure how to trigger it.

Comment: Note also the calling `printf()` from within a signal handler invokes undefined behavior. [Footnote 188 of the (draft) C11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188): "... a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions."  [POSIX allows for the calling of async-signal-safe functions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03_03) (page down some for the list).  `printf()` is not async-signal-safe. Windows has a similar list.

Comment: @Kinnturo Normally signals are sent by some other process or the OS. For instance, when you type Control-C, the OS sends SIGINT to the foreground processes. And you can use `kill -USR1 <pid>` to send `SIGUSR1` from the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`signal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/signal) only registers a signal handler - the function to be called when the process *receives* a signal. From within your program, you can use [`raise`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/raise) to *send* a signal to the calling process.

If you are in a POSIX environment, you should take a look at [`man 7 signal-safety`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) for a list of functions that are safe to call from within signal handlers (additional information in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16891799/2505965)). [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) is not included in this list - nor are a lot standard library functions. Its better to use an operation which is atomic with regards to signals, such as [`write`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) (or reentrant, such as [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen)).

A cursory example of using [`raise`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/raise), which returns `0` on success, and nonzero on error.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void my_handler(int signum) {
    char msg[] = "SIGUSR1 handler\n";

    if (signum == SIGUSR1)
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg, strlen(msg));
}

int main(void) {
    printf("Starting...\n");

    signal(SIGUSR1, my_handler);

    (void) getchar();

    if (raise(SIGUSR1) != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not raise signal.\n");
}
```